# Windows 8 - ListView using Horizontal items panel doesn't scroll

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-store

I have a `ListView` and I've simply replaced the `ItemsPanel` template with a `StackPanel` that's in horizontal mode, like so:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

However the items don't extend beyond the right hand side of the screen and thus, there's effectively no scrolling in any direction.

I copied the code from a //build/ session, so what did I miss?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You missed the configuration of the scroll viewer like this:

```
<ListView
   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" 
   ... > ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here your are the solutions. No changes for ScrollViewer is required. Default values work:

1) Vertical Scroll:

```
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

2) Horizontal Scroll:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <<ItemsWrapGrid/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Regards
Juanlu